# How to get odata.nextLink from the returned JSON object using oracle's apex_json

Tags: json, oracle, oracle-apex

I am retrieving data from an odata service. The response contains a link for loading more data i.e. odata.nextLink which I need to retrieve to load more data. How do I do this using oracle's apex_json? 
The server's response is something like this:

```
{
  "odata.metadata":"http://localhost:60497/odata/$metadata#tables","value":[
    {"id":001,"name":"abc" }

      .
      .
  ],
"odata.nextLink":"http://localhost:60497/odata/tables?$skip=10"
}
```

Normally I would parse the data and then retrieve the information like this `next_link := apex_json.get_varchar2('odata.nextLink');` but since it contains a point that won't work.

Answer (score 0):

In this case:

```
apex_json.get_varchar2('odata.nextLink');
```

it is considering nextLink as the value of odata.

```
DECLARE

v_json APEX_JSON.T_VALUES;
v_str_json VARCHAR2(4000);
next_link VARCHAR2(4000);

BEGIN


v_str_json := '{
  "odata" : {"nextLink" : "mylink"},
  "odata.metadata":"http://localhost:60497/odata/$metadata#tables","value":[
    {"id":001,"name":"abc" }
  ],
"odata.nextLink":"http://localhost:60497/odata/tables?$skip=10"
}
}';

APEX_JSON.PARSE(v_json, v_str_json);

next_link := APEX_JSON.GET_VARCHAR2(p_path => 'odata.nextLink', p_values => v_json);

dbms_output.put_line(next_link);

END;

>> OUTPUT: mylink
```

- I do not know how to say "odata.nextLink" to be interpreted literally; and not as a path.

If nobody knows:

1 - or stop sending "odata." at the beginning of the name of each attribute;

2 - or use replace to remove.

Comment: I have no control corncerning what the odata service outputs. Therefore for the time being I do (but I hope that there is a better solution):         apex_json.parse(replace(my_clob,'odata.nextLink', 'odata_nextLink') );
        link := apex_json.get_varchar2('odata_nextLink');